# Copy rotation of identical mesh with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms, normals

I am trying to use geometry nodes to automatically generate smear frames by stretching a mesh into an offset mesh.
Most of the time this works surprisingly well (Figure 2) until the two meshes differ too much in their rotation. In that case, the vertices are bundled in the middle because I don't take the rotation into account (Figure 3).

[image: smear frames]

Rotation seems to be a bigger problem. So I try to rotate one mesh in the same way as a second, identical mesh (rotation applied). But at this point, I am not getting anywhere.

[image: node tree rotation]

**EDIT:**
To make it more clear: I try to create smear frames, which are common in hand-drawn animation as a kind of stylized motion blur and to guide the eye through fast motions, like in this example.

[image]

As you can see in picture 2 it already works for pretty settle differences in the two frames, but if the difference in rotation is too big (seen in picture 3) I get really weird deformations. So I try to capture and apply the rotation of the target mesh (green) to the source mesh (red) on a vertex basis. In the end, this node tree is meant to be used with more complex, rigged meshes, which are also deformed. That's the reason I can't use regular rotation and location values.

**EDIT2:**
To make it even clearer:

[image]

1. simple animation of green Suzanne (should be a rigged character in the end)
2. duplicate animated mesh and offset it one frame (red)
3. use geometry nodes to stretch the second mesh (red) to first
4. Only the second mesh, which deforms on fast motion.

Here you can find the blend file, with both node trees

[image]

Comment: What exactly are your goals and what is your question? Could you edit the question and state what you want to achieve clearly and specifically and also ask an actual specific question? This would save some time for people who might try to help as they wouldn't have to guess and also risk to guess it wrong. I think you would be more likely to receive meaningful answers faster that way.

Comment: That's probably hard to explain in a few sentences, but I'll try my best. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: At the moment it is not clear how you might intend to use that node setup. It's just a node setup for a single stationary mesh. Animation is usually done with keyframes... How do these two things relate? Also why do you need 2 different meshes? Why do you want to use geometry nodes in the first place? Using armature would probably be more flexible, more intuitive to work with, easier to animate and would handle rotations well...

Comment: I feel like the explanation of what I'm trying to do is a little further away from the question at hand (how to transfer the rotation of the normals vertices from one mesh to another), but I've tried to explain it a little more clearly.

Comment: More context is always better. It helps to avoid [XY problems](https://xyproblem.info/) and helps people understand what solutions might work in a narrower context but will not work in broader context. For example the model being rigged changes situation quite a bit. It's a waste of time for people trying to help if they don't know essential information. In any case, there are techniques to do this besides Geometry Nodes that seem to be a lot more suitable for the purpose. It might be beneficial to ask about smear frames in general. But who knows, maybe someone will provide a GN based answer.